# How to print libstdc++ string content with dtrace

Tags: c++, macos, libstdc++, dtrace

I want to write a dtrace probe that would match a function with `std::string` argument and print the string's content:

```
void func(std::string some) {
    /* some code here */
}
```

I tried to implement the probe [like this](http://thr3ads.net/dtrace-discuss/2006/11/382336-DTrace-How-to-print-string-in-C):

```
pid$target::func(std??string):entry
{
    this->str = *(uintptr_t*)copyin(arg1, sizeof(char*));
    printf("arg1 %s", copyinstr(this->str));
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, dtrace reports it detected invalid address.. Also, there is another problem here - string in libstdc++ uses copy on write, so just coping a pointer is not enough here. Does anybody know how to do it? I'm using dtrace on mac os x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a working solution by myself. The probe in my question has a stupid mistake - arg0 should be copied instead of arg1. So the working probe is:

```
pid$target::func(*):entry 
{ 
    this->str = *((uintptr_t*)copyin(arg0, sizeof(void*)));
    printf("darg %s", copyinstr(this->str));
}
```

On the other hand for member function arg1 should be used:

```
class some {
    public:
        void func(const std::string arg) {
            std::cout << "arg " << arg << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Probe for function `some::func` should look like this:

```
pid$target::some??func(*):entry 
{ 
    this->str = *((uintptr_t*)copyin(arg1, sizeof(void*)));
    printf("darg %s", copyinstr(this->str));
}
```

This works for both libc++ and libstdc++ `std::string` classes. It even works if reference to string is used.